# Looking for a chess program that evaluates my playing and adapts its level to it

Tags: software, evaluation

As the title of the question says, I'm looking for a chess program that evaluates my playing and adapts its level to it. Maybe Lucas Chess does this (it's said that it does), but I found the tips of the movements I could play were full of mistakes... I don't have a lot of experience in this field and I know Lucas Chess is recommended by people who know chess much better than me.
But that was my experience.
So I started searching for other programs. I exchanged some e-mails with people at Schredder and they said the program does this, but it is expensive (in fact I don't mind, if it does this), and I want to do a good search. Maybe someone knows a good program for this kind of thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "evaluates my playing and adapts its level"? Shredder, for example, can adjust its level based on your ELO, which it automatically updates after every game (this feature is available in the normal version) - but I have a feeling you are looking for a something different. An example, perhaps?

Comment: I think he meant something like Shredder. Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Shredder app for IOS/Android has the following (optional) feature:

1. The program assigns to you a starting Elo.
2. When you play it, it adjusts its internal strength to match your Elo.
3. After the game, it adjusts your Elo based on the result.
4. The next game, it again adjusts its strength based on your Elo.

As you win more, it becomes more competitive until you reach a stage where your win ratio reaches around 50%.

About it being expensive - I recall paying about $5-10 for it, I guess it's up to you to decide whether that is worth the feature.

A few caveats from my experience:

1. The Elo calculated by Shredder is not a good estimate of your FIDE Elo. I stopped playing Shredder at around 1800, while my actual FIDE rating is less than 1600.
2. Shredder is better than most, but still not very good at simulating "human" play. This is especially noticeable at the lower strength settings - it will play like a GM for a few moves, then make a rather stupid tactical mistake, and then proceed to play like a GM.

If you are simply looking to have a bit of fun, then Shredder is great for that purpose, but if you are looking for a way to measure your playing strength as it would be against human opposition, it is simply not suitable for that - the only way you can measure how good you are against humans is to play humans.